# ByChained is not defined

Tags: javascript, selenium

I've been trying to use selenium webdriverjs in javascript to find the element that contains partial text "hoi" **and** text "hoe gaat het". I tried using ByChained, but it gives me an error that ByChained is not defined. How do i define ByChained in Javascript?

```
driver.findElement(new ByChained( By.partialLinkText("hoi"),(By.linkText("hoe gaat het")) ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you put these conditions together on the selector?

ex:

X And Y:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'hoi') and contains(text(),'hoe gaat het')]"))
```

X or Y:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'hoi') or contains(text(),'hoe gaat het')]"))
```

while it doesn't answer the question, it does give you a solution to your problem.